# RegEx multiple capture groups replaced in a string

Tags: regex, capture-group

I have a string of data...

```
"123456712J456","D","TEST1~TEST2~TEST3~TEST4~TEST5"
```

I want to take the following string and make 5 strings.

```
"123456712J456","D","TEST1"
"123456712J456","D","TEST2"
"123456712J456","D","TEST3"
"123456712J456","D","TEST4"
"123456712J456","D","TEST5"
```

I currently have the following regex...

```
//In a program like Textpad
<FIND> "\(.\{13\}\)","D","\([^~]*\)~\(.*\)
<REPLACE> "\1","D","\2"\n"\1","D","\3

//On the regex101 site
"(.{13})","D","([^~]*)~(.*)
```

Now if I run this 5 times it would work fine.  The problem is there is an unknown number of lines to be made.  For example...

```
"123456712J456","D","TEST1~TEST2~TEST3~TEST4~TEST5"
"123456712J457","D","TEST1~TEST2~TEST3"
"123456712J458","D","TEST1~TEST2"
"123456712J459","D","TEST1~TEST2~TEST3~TEST4"
```

I was hoping to be able to use a MULTI capture group to make this work.  I found this [PAGE](http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html) talking about the common mistake between repeating a capturing group and capturing a repeated group.  I need to capture a repeated group.  For some reason I just could not make mine work right though.  Anyone else have an idea?

---

**RESOURCES:**

- http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html
- http://regex101.com/

Comment: Sorry for all the crazy edits!  I kept the question like it was originally and created a new question for a more specific result.  Sorry again for all the craziness...  :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.See demo.Just club `match1` and `rest of the matches`.

http://regex101.com/r/yR3mM3/17

RegEx:

```
(.*,)|([^"~]+)
```

Example:

```
"1234567123456","T","TEST1~TEST2~TEST3~TEST4~TEST5"
```

Results:

```
MATCH 1
  1.    [0-20]  `"1234567123456","T",`

MATCH 2
  2.    [21-26] `TEST1`

MATCH 3
  2.    [27-32] `TEST2`

MATCH 4
  2.    [33-38] `TEST3`

MATCH 5
  2.    [39-44] `TEST4`

MATCH 6
  2.    [45-50] `TEST5`
```

Comment: I have no clue...  I +1'd it!  I added a little more too.  ;)  Thanks!!

Comment: I also have no clue why admdrew rejected my edit.  Comments are comments and answers are answers.  The reason for my edit was to clearly show what the regex in the answer does.  Saving users the effort of going to an external link!  My edit only served to better the answer and the comment on the rejection was rubbish.  Also, in comments you can not clearly show things in a code block such as my edit did...  Some people...

Comment: @ArvoBowen dont worry i have approved the edit.3 more and we are good to go :)